# I want to pass arguments from dag to trigger another dag

Tags: airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

The code below is a situation in which var1 and var2 are passed using the conf parameter when triggering another dag from the first dag.

```
trigger = TriggerDagRunOperator(
    trigger_dag_id='dag2',
    task_id="trigger",
    wait_for_completion=True,
    reset_dag_run=False,
    poke_interval=30,
    do_xcom_push=True,
    execution_date="{{ execution_date }}",
    conf={
            "var1": "{{ task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='task1', key='var1') }}",
            "var2": "{{ task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='task1', key='var2') }}",
    },
    dag=dag
)
```

In the second dag, I tried to print the var1 and var2 that are expected to be passed to conf.

```
def print_conf(**kwargs):
    conf = kwargs['dag_run'].conf
    print(conf)
    print(conf['var1'])
    print(conf['var2'])


print_op = PythonOperator(
    task_id='print',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=print_conf,
    dag=dag
)
```

But the output was that the values ​​of var1 and var2 were None.
{"var1": "None", "var2": "None"}

[image]

And even if I check the conf passed to the run in the airflow ui, the value was None.
How to pass arguments between dags through conf?
What could I have done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There are cases where it fails to import data saved with xcom_push to xcom_pull.
I solved it by using return_value from PythonOperator.

```
alter_table = EmrAddStepsOperator(
    task_id="alter_table",
    job_flow_name="rpda-emr",
    cluster_states=["WAITING", "RUNNING"],
    aws_conn_id="aws_default",
    steps="{{ task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='init_variables', key='return_value', dag_id=task_instance.dag_id)['alter_table_step'] 
}}",
    do_xcom_push=True,
    dag=dag
)
```